# EmberJS captures jQuery AJAX, breaking result handling

Tags: jquery, ajax, ember.js

I'm currently building my first app with Ember, and it's a re-work of a major site (one that deals with mortgages), and in the first iteration, I'm keeping much of old functionality and just implementing the navigation with Ember and Handlebars.

The problem I have now is that when performing an address auto-complete from the original site, the result display parsing broke (note that this call is not made through Ember, but another module which only implements jQuery) and when troubleshooting, I saw that when the JSON-array from the server was traversed, the loop contained one more object than the actual server response: an `Ember.Array.Ember.Mixin.create.nextObject`.

I've been searching around, but haven't been able to find out why or where this item is pushed to the server response. Please note again that this request is made through jQuery only; no Ember functionality is actively implemented on the request.

I can only assume that Ember captures the original jQuery AJAX-call in some way. If so, how do I prevent this?

Thank you for your time.

Best regards,
dimhoLt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember extends the `Array` prototype. Which means that all arrays defined inside a page that includes Ember will have many more methods than the usual. This is usually great.

You can turn it off, of course:
http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/

But maybe in future iterations, once you manage to integrate Ember all over the place, you can turn them on and refactor your code. The extensions are definitely useful and will make your life easier

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, this was the answer to my question. Thank you! Looking forward to when I can refactor the site to implement all functionality from Ember.